# Почему Collection<String> преобразуется в record[] postgresql spring jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Имеется такая функция в postgresql

```
CREATE FUNCTION server_delete (
    remove_station_id bigint,
    server_names varchar(60)[]
)
    RETURNS TABLE (
                station_id integer,
                server_name varchar,
                code        integer
            )
```

Пытаюсь её вызвать через Spring JPA

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM server_delete(:id, ARRAY [:names])", nativeQuery = true)
List<ServerDeleteProjection> deleteByStationIdAndServerNameIn(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("names") Collection<String> names);
```

Получаю ошибку

```
[SqlExceptionHelper.java:142] ERROR: function server_delete(bigint, record[]) does not exist
  Подсказка: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

1. Почему коллекция строк стала record?
2. Как можно вызвать функцию через JPA (hibernate)?